# OnClickListener the same with other layout

Tags: android, layout, listener

I change my layout in my activity with `setContentView()`. I have two layouts with the same elements and ids. I register the `onClickListener` for the elements in my `onCreate` method.

Somehow the `onClicklistners` do not work before and not after the change of the layout.

Comment: What for do you need "two layouts with the same elements and ids"?

Comment: the elements just have another position in the layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please change your id if your doing it in the same activity.